# Rails Two step Authentication client time mismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

In my app i had implemented two-step authentication(rails4.0.9) and tested it, its working perfectly but some of my clients were facing issues. After sometime i realised that server time and client's time are not matching(i thought some of them set their time 10mins fast/slow). Is there any way to solve this problem?(like amazon aws) how to implement it? currently i am using Active model otp gem [git_link](https://github.com/heapsource/active_model_otp) anyone please suggest some good idea. If any information needed just comment it out i will update my question Thanks

Comment: Could you please explain how are you using client time? I think you should use only server time for two-step authentication.

Comment: @maxd i am not using client time, but google authenticator uses current time (in client's mobile)  + shared secret to generate code, rails server time+shared secret gives code here (client may change time in his/her mobile) thats the problem